# extract embedded barcode from a PDF

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

When I try to use "[pdfimages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfimages)" to extract barcode from PDF, for example, [this one](https://www.antennahouse.com/product/img/barcode-sample3.pdf). Initially, I thought these barcodes are images, but maybe not because based on my test pdfimages is not able to extract them into image files. It does extract QR codes but not ordinary barcodes.

So my question is; Is there a way to extract a barcode from a PDF as "image" (I don't want a scan, only image)? Also, I prefer CLI on my Ubuntu system.